# How to update flutter widget using RxDart BehaviorSubject?

Tags: dart, flutter, rxdart

Im new to flutter and dart so i have created simple counter flutter app , explained in article.

But when stream does not update widget when subject adds values.
can someone help me to find the issue.

my main widget class

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  CounterBloc _counterBloc = new CounterBloc(initialCount: 0);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Counter(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _counterBloc.increment,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

and Counter widget

```
class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CounterState createState() => _CounterState();
}

class _CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  CounterBloc _counterBloc = new CounterBloc(initialCount: 1);
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _counterBloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _counterBloc.counterObservable,
      builder: (context, snapshot) => Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                ),
                Text(
                  '${snapshot.hasData}',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is my bloc class

```
class CounterBloc {
  int initialCount =
      1; //if the data is not passed by paramether it initializes with 0
  BehaviorSubject<int> _subjectCounter;

  CounterBloc({this.initialCount}) {
    _subjectCounter = new BehaviorSubject<int>.seeded(
        this.initialCount); //initializes the subject with element already
  }

  Observable<int> get counterObservable => _subjectCounter.stream;

  void increment() {
    initialCount++;
    print(initialCount);
    _subjectCounter.add(initialCount);
  }

  void decrement() {
    initialCount--;
    _subjectCounter.add(initialCount);
  }

  void dispose() {
    _subjectCounter.close();
  }
}
```

Can some one help me to find the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using two separate instances of `CounterBloc` in `MyHomePage` and `Counter` classes. A simple solution would be to pass the `CounterBloc` of `MyHomePage` to `Counter`:

**MyHomePage**

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
```

**MyHomePageState**

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  CounterBloc _counterBloc = CounterBloc(initialCount: 0);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Counter(
        bloc: _counterBloc,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _counterBloc.increment,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

**Counter**

```
class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  Counter({Key key, this.bloc}) : super(key: key);

  final CounterBloc bloc;
  @override
  _CounterState createState() => _CounterState();
}
```

**CounterState**

```
class _CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  CounterBloc _counterBloc;
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _counterBloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CounterBloc _counterBloc = widget.bloc;
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _counterBloc.counterObservable,
      builder: (context, snapshot) => Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '${snapshot.data}',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But in the long run, rather than passing your `Bloc` explicitly as a parameter, you should use a `BlocProvider`, which will implicitly assigns the instance of the parent classes' `Bloc` to your children.

Comment: could you please provide sample blocprovider , a simple one! and add little explanation about provider.

Comment: It's fully explained in this great article https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/12/reactive-programming---streams---bloc---practical-use-cases/

Comment: Thank you! Yes it is a great article.